# How to do selective preposition tagging nltk

Tags: python, nltk, tagging, part-of-speech

NLTK preposition tagging includes many words such as - in, at, of, as ,by , during ... etc.

I want to tag only selective words - in, at,per - as 'IN'.

Rest of the prepositions should be tagged differently - say 'ZZ' - meaning these can be deleted later.

Example:

```
"ABCD achieved 2 million orders in September in Africa during summer sales. "

Expected Output:
in - should be  tagged as IN
in - should be tagged as IN
during - should be tagged as ZZ
```

Comment: You have two choices: Post-process the tagger's output (easiest, if you can _always_ predict the new tag based on the word being tagged), or generate a tagged training set and train a new tagger. This would only make sense if there were context-dependent differences, e.g. if the word "of" must sometimes be tagged as "IN", sometimes as something else.

Answer (score 1):

Loop over the tagged output and replace IN with ZZ if the word is not in ('in', 'at', 'per').